# Is there an equivalent of the Azure Integration Runtime for AWS Data pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-data-factory, aws-data-pipeline

I have previously had successful implementations of data transfer from on-premise SQL Server instances to Azure SQL using the Integration Runtime component in conjunction with Azure Data Factory.

I am not very familiar with AWS but from what I have read, the AWS Data Pipleine in the AWS equivalent of the Azure Data Factory.

If I wanted to transfer data from an on-premise SQL Server instance using the AWS Data Pipeline is there an equivalent component to the Integration Runtime that I need to use, or is there a different recommended approach?

Comment: Did you try the JDBCdatabase https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-jdbcdatabase.html?